# Why can't I get the shape of this numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I am importing a matlab file using `scipy.io`, and trying to find its dimensions. It seems, even though the file is getting loaded into python, it's not able to give the dimensions. Why is that? And how to fix this?

```
>>> import scipy.io
>>> pref_mat = scipy.io.loadmat('pref_mat_loc.mat')
>>> R=pref_mat
>>> import numpy
>>> R=numpy.array(R)
>>> len(R)
0
>>> R # We see that the first line of the file is getting printed, means the file has been loaded.

array({'pref_mat': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16), '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Mon May 08 23:42:05 2017', '__version__': '1.0', '__globals__': []}, dtype=object)

>>> len(R.shape) # But it appears here as though R is empty
0
>>> R.shape # As does here
()
```

Comment: `len(R.shape)` is the same as `R.ndim` for future reference.

Comment: What is the purpose of `R=pref_mat`? Why not just `R = scipy.io.loadmat(...)`?

Comment: Why in the name of ... are you doing `R=numpy.array(R)`? Do you understand what `loadmat` returns?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why? What happened? I am not a regular python user, I just happpen to require it for this particular job. As I understand, `loadmat` loads the matlab file; I don't know what it returns though. Is it a dictionary?

Comment: It sure does. Have a look at your own output and the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pref_mat`, returned by `loadmat` is a dictionary.  You have wrapped it in an array, `R`.  I can deduce the contents of `pref_mat` as the {} part of `R`:

```
{'pref_mat': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16), 
'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Mon May 08 23:42:05 2017', 
'__version__': '1.0', 
'__globals__': []}
```

So the array you are interested in is

```
R = pref_mat['pref_mat']
```

That `R` should have the shape and dtype that you want. Though in summary view I only see 0's.

If the MATLAB had saved cells or structs the nesting of 'object' type arrays would get more complicated.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works. The data is ok, its a sparse matrix, hence the 0s. :)