# How to load and convert .mat file into numpy 2D array?

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, opencv, python

I have a data in mat file (observations and features) and i want to load it into numpy 2D array. I dont want to convert it into csv first and then load csv into numpy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875194/why-cant-i-get-the-shape-of-this-numpy-array illustrates loading a simple MATLAB matrix.  If you have cells or structs the loaded dictionary is more complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [scipy's loadmat (API-docs)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html).

The docs should be sufficient to get you going, but make sure to read the notes.

There is also the [io-tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/tutorial/io.html) with some examples.

Comment: So useful. The loadmat() returns a dict type and we can get the array by its key.