# How to read .mat file format in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

There are three builds in Reader in Tensorflow.

1. `tf.TFRecordReader`, used for reading TFRecord file
2. `tf.FixedLengthRecordReader`, used for reading binary file
3. `tf.TextLineReader`, used for reading CSV file

**But how should I read a .mat file format? Which reader should I use? Is there any reader for reading .mat file?**

***Description***: 
Currently, I am making a small CNN model for classifying housing number using [Street View Housing Number](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) dataset. The dataset uses .mat file format .It is a large dataset. It will be helpful if I read the dataset using the Tensorflow build in reading mechanism. But which reader should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have an optimized solution, you should read and convert your data to one of the supported formats:

1. Read the `.mat` file.  I suggest using [`scipy.io`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html) for reading the `.mat` files.
2. Store it in one of the supported formats.  The recommended format for TensorFlow is a `TFRecords` file containing `tf.train.Example` protocol buffers (which contain `Features` as a field) [quoted from here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#file_formats).

Good luck!

Comment: [quoted from here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#file_formats) link is invalid

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `TFRecords` here is one way to use `tf.py_func` to get `.mat` files imported via the `tf.data.Dataset` API.

```
def read_mat(filepath):   
    def _read_mat(filepath):
        matfile = sio.loadmat(filepath)
        data0 = matfile['data0']
        data1 = matfile['data1']
        data2 = mat_contents['data2']
        shape0 = matfile['data0'].shape
        return data0, data1, data2, np.asarray(shape0)

    output = tf.py_func(_read_mat, [filepath], [tf.double, tf.uint16, tf.double, tf.int64])
    shape = output[3]
    data0 = tf.reshape(output[0], shape)
    data1 = tf.reshape(output[1], shape)
    data2 = tf.reshape(output[2], shape)
    return data0, data1, data2

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('*.mat')
dataset = dataset.map(read_mat, num_parallel_calls=16)
dataset = dataset.repeat(100)
dataset = dataset.batch(8)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(8)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
values = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

Comment: For Tensorflow v2 tf.py_func can be swapped for tf.numpy_function

Answer (score -2):

I think the better way to load data in your tensorflow model is probably to convert your .mat to numpy format manually.

Numpy is very adaptable with TensorFlow and you can easily find other post which can help you.

Check that [How to load and convert .mat file into numpy 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952620/8819908)

Hope it can help you !

Answer (score -2):

All you need is importing "scipy.io" package to read mat file in python. [loadmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/tutorial/io.html) will be imported from this package.

For example:

```
import scipy.io as sio
mat_contents = sio_loadmat('myMatFile.mat')
```

Good luck!