# Cannot load VGG19 ImageNet weights stored in a ".mat" file on disk

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I'm trying out transfer learning and I have downloaded weights for VGG19 model from ImageNet dataset. It downloaded as a ".mat" file. At first I tried to load in the entire .mat file as

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19

model_path = os.path.join('trained_model', 'imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat')
pre_trained_model = VGG19(weights = None, include_top = False)
pre_trained_model.load_weights(model_path)
```

but, I got the following error.

```
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

Then I tried the `set_weights()` method instead of `load_weights()`, as

```
pre_trained_model = VGG19(weights = None, include_top = False)
pre_trained_model.set_weights(model_path)
```

then I got the following error,

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "vgg19" with a weight list of length 42, 
but the layer was expecting 32 weights. Provided weights: trained_model\imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat...
```

I have also tried

```
pre_trained_model = VGG19(weights = None, include_top = True)
pre_trained_model.set_weights(model_path)
```

but, I still get the same errors.

I have downloaded the weights from https://www.kaggle.com/teksab/imagenetvggverydeep19mat

Answer (score 0):

you can't load weights cause layer size are different.

here is the way you can :
[How to read .mat file format in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890387/how-to-read-mat-file-format-in-tensorflow?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This line `pre_trained_model = VGG19(weights = None, include_top = False)`
`include_top = False` means that the model does not load the fully connected layers. Have you checked if the pretrained model on Kaggle uses `include_top = True?`

Comment: Yes, I have. I should've included that in the question